# Converting Dataset from 'Wide' to 'Long' in Google Apps Script for Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help generating a google script AND/or Formula for this one..

In the attached gsheet below, I have the following raw dataset...

[image: Raw Data]

For Phase 1, I need to convert this 'wide' format to a 'long'  format whereby new columns are created for each attribute in 'Data Type' and 'T1' and 'T2' are condensed in their own column called 'Time'.  Please see below...
[image]

For Phase 2, I need to join all info across each row but split by 'Time'.  Please see below...
[image]

Finally for Phase 3, I need to create one additional step where each is split by Col A.  Please see below...
[image]

I have tried to achieve the reshaping of the data via 'QUERY'and 'Transpose' but can't seem to do it.  If anyone has a custom build function that addresses this very common task, I would very much appreciate your help on this one!

Dataset is below...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ujxki1wmaLmkBgZQHI-OTwSubKdlN5mvLDdGWhCBn3E/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? I'm interested in the situation of your issue. So I challenged this. This is also for my study. In my answer, I tried to solve your question using GAS. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

In this sample script, the values for "Phase 1", "Phase 2" and "Phase 3" are created every 1 cycle of the data. From your question and sample spreadsheet, I thought that the cycle of data is 5. Then, the created values are imported the 3 sheets.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawData = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = rawData[0];
  var delimiter = "| "; // Please input delimiter.
  var cycle = 5; // From your question, I thought the cycle of data is 5.

  var phase1 = [];
  var phase2 = [];
  var phase3 = [];
  rawData.shift();
  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i += cycle) {
    var temp1 = [];
    var temp2 = [];
    for (var j = i; j < i + cycle; j++) {
      temp1.push([rawData[j][0], rawData[j][1]]);
      temp2.push([rawData[j][3], rawData[j][4]]);
    }
    var converted = temp2[0].map(function(_, i){return temp2.map(function(f){return f[i]})}) // Transpose
                            .map(function(e, i){return temp1[i].concat(e).concat(header[i + 3])}); // Add T1 and T2

    // Create value for phase1.
    Array.prototype.push.apply(phase1, converted);

    // Create value for phase2.
    phase2.push([converted[0].slice(0, 7).join(delimiter), converted[1].slice(0, 7).join(delimiter)]);

    // Create value for phase3.
    phase3.push([converted[0][0], header[3], header[4]]);
    phase3.push(["", converted[0].slice(1, 7).join(delimiter), converted[1].slice(1, 7).join(delimiter)]);
    phase3.push(["", "", ""]);
  }

  // If you want to change the sheet name, please modify this part.
  var all = [
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 1"), phase1],
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 2"), phase2],
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 3(Desired Final Output)"), phase3]
  ];
  all.forEach(function(e) {
    // Import values to 3 sheets.
    e[0].getRange(e[0].getLastRow() + 1, 1, e[1].length, e[1][0].length).setValues(e[1]);
  });
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit

1. When the modified script is run, all converted values are overwrote for 3 sheets of phase 1, phase 2 and phase 3.
2. The name of `Data Melt` can't be used for the function name. So `DataMelt` was used for it.

   - For example, `=DataMelt('Raw Data'!A2:E6)` is put to a cell, the converted data for phase 1 is imported.
   - **In this function, the data that 5 rows are 1 cycle can be used.**

#### Modified script

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawData = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = rawData[0];
  var delimiter = "| "; // Please input delimiter.
  var cycle = 5; // From your question, I thought the cycle of data is 5.

  var phase1 = [];
  var phase2 = [];
  var phase3 = [];
  rawData.shift();
  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i += cycle) {
    var temp1 = [];
    var temp2 = [];
    for (var j = i; j < i + cycle; j++) {
      temp1.push([rawData[j][0], rawData[j][1]]);
      temp2.push([rawData[j][3], rawData[j][4]]);
    }
    var converted = temp2[0].map(function(_, i){return temp2.map(function(f){return f[i]})}) // Transpose
                            .map(function(e, i){return temp1[i].concat(e).concat(header[i + 3])}); // Add T1 and T2

    // Create value for phase1.
    Array.prototype.push.apply(phase1, converted);

    // Create value for phase2.
    phase2.push([converted[0].slice(0, 7).join(delimiter), converted[1].slice(0, 7).join(delimiter)]);

    // Create value for phase3.
    phase3.push([converted[0][0], header[3], header[4]]);
    phase3.push(["", converted[0].slice(1, 7).join(delimiter), converted[1].slice(1, 7).join(delimiter)]);
    phase3.push(["", "", ""]);
  }
  phase1.unshift(["Col A", "Col B", "Catalogue", "Display", "Equivalent Single Price", "In-Store_Shopper", "Mechanic", "Time"]);
  phase2.unshift(["T1", "T2"]);
  var all = [
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 1"), phase1],
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 2"), phase2],
    [ss.getSheetByName("Phase 3(Desired Final Output)"), phase3]
  ];
  all.forEach(function(e) {
    // Import values to 3 sheets.
    e[0].getRange(1, 1, e[1].length, e[1][0].length).setValues(e[1]);
  });
}

// Added new function
function DataMelt(e) {
  var e = [["Chalk","A0C-Len Superior Kids TP 80gm","Catalogue","No","Yes"],["Chalk","A0C-Len Superior Kids TP 80gm","Display","Shelf","GE"],["Chalk","A0C-Len Superior Kids TP 80gm","Equivalent Single Price",2.49,2.49],["Chalk","A0C-Len Superior Kids TP 80gm","In-Store_Shopper","",""],["Chalk","A0C-Len Superior Kids TP 80gm","Mechanic","LDLP","Off"]];

  var rawData = e;
  var header = ["Col A", "Col B", "Data Type", "T1", "T2"];
  var cycle = 5; // From your question, I thought the cycle of data is 5.
  var phase1 = [];
  var temp1 = [];
  var temp2 = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < cycle; j++) {
    temp1.push([rawData[j][0], rawData[j][1]]);
    temp2.push([rawData[j][3], rawData[j][4]]);
  }
  var converted = temp2[0].map(function(_, i){return temp2.map(function(f){return f[i]})}) // Transpose
                          .map(function(e, i){return temp1[i].concat(e).concat(header[i + 3])}); // Add T1 and T2

  // Create value for phase1.
  Array.prototype.push.apply(phase1, converted);
  return phase1;
}
```

Comment: @ Tanaike  Thank you so much for this.  At this point in time, I have two questions 1.) When data is edited in the raw data tab, is it possible for the script to be tweaked so that replaces all the data in phase 1, phase 2 & phase 3? (rather than simply appending all the imported values to the next available empty row as it does at the moment).  2) Is it possible to create a custom function called 'Data Melt' where I could parse the raw data as an argument and produce the same output as phase 1?

Comment: @jwlon81 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If the modified scripts didn't work, please tell me.